# Odoo 15 Label Field Too Wide

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

In the Odoo 15, I realize that the width of the label for the field is too wide. When I inspect the element in the browser, the CSS that causing this behaviour is this one:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.o_web_client:not(.o_chatter_position_sided) .o_action_manager .o_content .o_inner_group .o_td_label,
.o_web_client:not(.o_chatter_position_sided) .o_action_manager .modal-content .o_inner_group .o_td_label {
        min-width: 260px !important;
}
```

I already try to change some CSS that I think related to this behaviour from the source code, but still not working. How to change this default width?

[image]

Comment: Without seeing the HTML/CSS, there is no way for us to know what exactly is causing that spacing. Please provide a minimal code example. ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: I will delete the css tag, so only Odoo community will see this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using web responsive module ? If yes, look at

```
web/web_responsive/static/src/legacy/scss/web_responsive.scss
```

file as well to make same changes as you did.

Otherwise, changing `min-width` should work fine

**Note:** Do not edit at source.  Make a new module, inherit those and change.